# Identify offending nodes

Tags: polkadot

When a node if offline, ImOnLine reports something like this:

Someoffline:
[
5EFRkbkfT6Sxjmkb6MiSyG8TAnVwV4KBk1BWfZnQ3XL14uxq,
{
total: 79.2000 kTOK,
own: 79.2000 kkTOK,
others: []
}
]

How can I know which node or account 5EFRkbkfT6Sxjmkb6MiSyG8TAnVwV4KBk1BWfZnQ3XL14uxq is referring to? I mean, how can I find the physical node (IP/DNS for example)?

Thanks very much.
regards;
fernando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the on-chain data, you can map to the actual stash.

The key reported by ImOnline is part of the session keys, i.e. [session.nextKeys](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#nextkeysaccountid32-optionnoderuntimesessionkeys). You have 2 options -

- retrieve all the entries of the session.nextKeys map and check the above for the specific ImOnline key (expensive)
- query the [keyOwner](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#keyownerspcorecryptokeytypeidbytes-optionaccountid32) for the specific key

Both will trace you back to the actual stash. There is no specific mapping from stash -> IP in the online runtime storage.

Comment: Excelent! Thanks very much Jaco! Really appreciate it.